# types.MethodType/inspect.ismethod doesn't seem to work on all functions

Tags: python, unreal-engine4

I've tried all the methods described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091259/how-to-test-if-a-class-attribute-is-an-instance-method) and wondering if there are limitations if dealt with non-native libraries?

```
import unreal
print(unreal.load_asset)
>>> <built-in function load_asset>
```

Now when I run

```
import inspect
inspect.ismethod(getattr(unreal, 'load_asset'))
>>> False
```

Is this a C++ Binding issue? Any details on how type check handles this?

Comment: [`unreal.load_asset`](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/PythonAPI/module/unreal.html#unreal.load_asset)?  What makes you think that's a method? Looks like a module level function..

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I should actually have called `hasattr(unreal.load_asset, '__call__')` to check if it's a function or not, or in my case if it's a callable or not.